# Can you use the Healing Extra Restorative to heal loss of Toughness (-x Toughness save) due to failed damage saved from combat?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Can you use the Healing Extra Restorative to heal loss of Toughness (-x Toughness save) due to save vs damage?

> Restorative: Your Healing effect can restore character points removed by Weaken effects with the appropriate descriptors, such as injury, disease, or poison. You restore points equal to your rank to the affected trait(s).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I did reword it enough that I got much more satisfactory answer the way it was asked. My apologizes.

Comment: No worries. :) I had thought I'd seen a similar question before. By the by the official forums for M&M are at http://roninarmy.com. You can ask questions there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

The power Extra specifically targets *Weaken* effects.

**Yes**

Regular Healing will remove those penalties.

> You can heal Damage conditions by touching a subject and taking a standard action to make a DC 10 Healing check. Each degree of success healing one Damage condition, starting with the subject’s worst condition, and working down, as if the subject were recovering rapidly. If the subject is dying, the highest degree of success stabilizes the subject, removing the dying condition. If the Healing check fails, you must wait one minute or use extra effort in order to try again.

The "-1 penalties" are each damage conditions.

**Maybe**

It does not specify in the description whether Restorative Healing is considered separate from a regular Healing, so you might be doing both at once. And, of course, your GM may have their own interpretation.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much we've been mulling over how to get heal "-1 pen" to Toughness never once considering it itself is a damage condition.